# how to separate values in a column in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have an excel file with two columns time and output.
output column consist of two values 1 and 2. 
I want to make a calculate total time output 2 last in continuity i.e end time -start time.
for example

```
    time          output       total
      2                2           4-2=2
      4                2
      6                1
      8                2           10-8=2
      10               2
      12               1
      14               1
      16               1
      18               2           22-18=4
      20               2
      22               2
```

Is there some easy way to so this as my data file is very large

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Several issues with your post. 1) The headline doesn't correspond very well with your question, 2) Third example  in total column seems to be incorrect, it should be 20-18=2, shouldn't it? 3) If I understand you correctly, you could achieve this by adding "=A3-A2" in [C2] and copy-pasting the formula to the bottom row. Completely standard...

Comment: ya its suppose to be 20-18=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(B2=2,B1<>2),INDEX($A2:$A$30000,MATCH(1,$B2:$B$30000,0)-1)-A2,"")
```

The only caveat is that the last value in column B needs to be a 1.  Or it will not do the last calculation correctly.

[image]

---

If you have Excel 2010 or later this formula does not care about the last values in column B. But depending the number of rows it will be slower in the calculations.

```
=IF(AND(B2=2,B1<>2),INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(2:$13)/($B2:$B$13 <>2),1)-1)-A2,"")
```

[image]

But it does require that the last row in the specified ranges be at least one larger than the last data row.  It can be thousands larger, but that adds calculation times.

Comment: @amy Please mark answer as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.  It will close the question as answered and reward me with points.